# HttpWebRequest - (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: wcf

I have a SOAP Envelop logged in Database using **IDispatchMessageInspector**. I need to invoke my WCF Service having wsHttpBinding using the SOAP Envlope.

I am using below code to invoke my WCF Service.

```
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("ServiceURL");
        req.Method = "POST";
        string reqBody = theBomRequest; //it has entire soap
        byte[] reqBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqBody);
        req.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
        req.GetRequestStream().Write(reqBodyBytes, 0, reqBodyBytes.Length);
        req.GetRequestStream().Close();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
        if (resp.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        }
        resp.Close();
```

At GetResponse, I'm getting *(500) Internal Server Error*

Thanks,
Akif

Comment: 500 means the problem is on the server side, so your client won't get more information than that. What is happening on the server side? Do you have access to output or logs from your WCF service? What do they say?

Comment: You will need to get to the server to find out the real error. If not possible, contact the owner of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Enable **[Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)** on your Service and see what is the cause for exception.